# JUnit 5 for Android testing

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, junit5

How to configure JUnit 5 for Android unit testing?
I tried:

```
testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0")
```

But it doesn't work, when I run previous the simplest unit test:

```
@Test
public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
}
```

I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.loadTestEngines(ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.java:31)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:42)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:36)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
Empty test suite.
```

Comment: Related post: [How to use JUnit 5 with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44429751/8583692)

Answer (score 34):

#### Refer to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127100532) and [this issue](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/224) regarding JUnit 5 support on Android.

Add this build script dependency in your **top-level** *build.gradle[.kts]* file:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath("de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:1.8.2.1")
  }
}
```

And add these lines in your **app** or library *build.gradle[.kts]* file:

```
plugins {
  // ...
  id("de.mannodermaus.android-junit5")
}

dependencies {
  // Aggregator dependency on JUnit api, engine, and params
  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.1")
  // (Optional) If you also have JUnit 4-based tests
  testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.1")
}
```

You can use the above solution if you are using **Android Gradle plugin 3.2.0 or higher** and **Gradle 4.7 or higher**. For more information refer to the [plugin GitHub page](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5).

## Extended answer

If you want to use JUnit 5 in your instrumented tests (*androidTest* source set) do the following:

1. Add these dependencies to your **app** or libray build script:

```
androidTestImplementation("de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-core:1.3.0")
androidTestRuntimeOnly("de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-runner:1.3.0")
```

2. Use `ActivityScenarioExtension` instead of `ActivityScenarioRule` in your test classes:

```kotlin
import de.mannodermaus.junit5.ActivityScenarioExtension

class MyActivityTest {

  @JvmField
  @RegisterExtension
  val scenarioExtension = ActivityScenarioExtension.launch<MyActivity>()

  @Test
  fun test1() {
    val scenario = scenarioExtension.scenario
    scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    assertThat(scenario.state).isEqualTo(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
  }

  @Test
  fun test2(scenario: ActivityScenario<MyActivity>) {
    scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    assertThat(scenario.state).isEqualTo(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio is based on IDEA, correct?

Then see this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46161799/1431016 or read directly the user-guide at http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea

Summary:

```
// Only needed to run tests in an IntelliJ IDEA that bundles an older version
testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0")
testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.0")
```

I didn't try this project yet, but it could help you using JUnit 5 on Android: https://github.com/aurae/android-junit5

Answer (score 3):

You can use the official version by adding these lines to your gradle file:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()
    }
  }
}



dependencies {
     testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.0"
}
```

To continue to run your JUnit4 tests alongside Junit5, add:

```
testImplementation "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.8.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

It is January 2023 and the answers here that used to work, do not work for me on Android Studio 2021.3.1 (Patch 1), running Gradle 7.4.

This is what I did to make mine work:

1. First, attempted to follow the answer by @Mahozad. I chose it because it referred to the [latest junit-jupiter:5.9.1 version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53674289/2597758).
2. But my app's `build.gradle` did not like the `plugins {...}` section from there, so I used `apply plugin: 'de.mannodermaus.android-junit5'` instead, from [@BoonKeatTeo's article](https://medium.com/@boonkeat/android-unit-testing-with-junit5-d1b8f9c620b6).
3. Still, it would not recognize any of the imported symbols and so I added the [repository URL from @DagnogoJean-François's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60040706/2597758) (File > Settings > Build... > Remote Jar Repositories)
4. It continued complaining about an `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;` added to Test class and after running from the command line `gradlew build --warning-mode=all`, I realized that it is a good idea to remove the **deprecated** `jcenter` repository. In addition to removing it via Settings, I replaced all `jcenter()` occurrences with `mavenCentral()` in the root build.gradle.
5. I still had the import warning, so I decided to remove all imports and accept the suggestion by Android Studio to add a `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1` dependency. This seems to have done the magic and now there are no warnings on any of my Test class symbols.

To summarize, here is how my build.gradle looks now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'de.mannodermaus.android-junit5'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "33.0.1"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    namespace 'com.susu.mylib'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 33
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:5.1.0"

    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1'
}
```

Comments on how to improve this further are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**USE ALWAYS THE OFFICIAL VERSION**

First go to the **official documentation** of Junit here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api
you will see all latest version like this 
[image]

then in your app/gradle add this dependencie :

> testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:X.X.X')

where X.X.X is the version you want.
For example in my case it was

> testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.0')

Comment: I agree with you but the official version doesn't work with instrumentation tests.
If you add
androidTestImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:X.X.X')
you encounter by some errors

Answer (score 0):

Adding the android-junit5 plugin solves the problem

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    // use JUnit5 for tests
    id("de.mannodermaus.android-junit5") version "1.10.0.0"
}
```

[android-junit5](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5)