# How to disable some JUnit 5 Android instrumented tests on GitHub Actions?

Tags: junit, github-actions, junit5, android-testing

I have an instrumented test class. Its test cases are in JUnit 5 (with the help of a Gradle plugin per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53674289/8583692)). How can I disable this test class from being run on CI (specifically, on GitHub Actions)?

I cannot use JUnit 5 annotations like `@DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable` because Android instrumented tests run on the device/emulator and cannot see the Host OS environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All GitHub workflows have access to an environment variable `CI` which is always `true` ([Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables)).

With that in mind, we can disable our test class indirectly using Gradle.
In order to do that, declare a buildConfig field like this in your *app/build.gradle[.kts]*:

```kotlin
android {
  buildTypes {
    getByName("debug") {
      val isCI = System.getenv("CI")?.toBoolean() ?: false
      buildConfigField("Boolean", "CI", "$isCI")
    }
// ...
```

Disable the test class/method with `@DisabledIfBuildConfigValue` provided by [the plugin](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5) like so:

```kotlin
@DisabledIfBuildConfigValue(named = "CI", matches = "true")
class ScreenshotTest {
// ...
```

Executing the tests with Gradle, the above classes/methods will be skipped when run on GitHub:

```sh
./gradlew :app:connectedAndroidTest --stacktrace
```