# How to pass arguments to Espresso UI Tests from command line using ADB?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-espresso, android-testing

I am just starting with Espresso to write UI automation tests. I am able to setup the environment and run tests using ADB command.

adb shell am instrument -w -e class codepath.apps.demointroandroid.EspressoDemo#ValidateApplicationIsLaunched codepath.apps.demointroandroid.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

codepath.apps.demointroandroid.EspressoDemo is the class name containing the tests.
ValidateApplicationIsLaunched is the Espresso test case ran using ADB.

Now my question is how to pass any argument to Espresso test case from the command line?

Consider the following use case.

1. Design a test case for creating a user account.
2. Now I want to run this test case with different parameters e.g. Name, Age etc. which I want to control via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that passing parameters to test via Android console like NAME or AGE is possible, but...

... why don't you create test classes (one for every test case) and run specific one using gradle console like in example below:
[Running a specific unit test with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565857/running-a-specific-unit-test-with-gradle)

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Although it's technically possible using a [custom test runner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15198415/1231827), it sounds like you might want to use [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) instead.