# Running Instrumented Test with arguments using command prompt

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I've an InstrumentedTest

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext(String groupName) {
Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        UiDevice device=UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
...
...
  }
}
```

And I want to execute it using `adb shell` command. But I've to pass value of `groupName` parameter for the method `useAppContext(String groupName)`

I was using command

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.<package_name>.ExampleInstrumentedTest' com.<package_name>.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

But how can I pass method parameters as arguments to the command running over command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Ref :  [How to pass an argument to an AndroidTestCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188756/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-an-androidtestcase/15198415#15198415)

```
public class MyTestRunner extends InstrumentationTestRunner {

    public static String BAR;

    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {

        if (null != arguments) {    
            BAR = (String) arguments.get("foo"));
        }    
        super.onCreate(arguments);
    }
}
```

I added to Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android.test.runner
```

And to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<instrumentation 
    android:name="com.example.MyTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.example" />
```

Ran it using this command line:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e foo the_value_of_bar com.example/com.example.MyTestRunner
```

**Edit 2**

This sounds like the Parameterised JUnit Test use-case.

Check out the brief tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/) - note that you will need to be using JUnit4 and I'm not sure Android's testing framework is ready for that.

That said, JUnit4 is backward compatible to JUnit3 so in-theory it'll be possible to use JUnit4 annotations under the android test case runner with a bit of build path tomfoolery.

Comment: so this will be a part of Android Instrumented Test?

Answer (score 2):

one can pass arguments with [adb am instrument](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am):

```
adb push ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/com.<package_name>-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.<package_name>.debug
adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.<package_name>.debug"
adb push ./app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/com.<package_name>-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/com.<package_name>.debug.test
adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.<package_name>.debug.test"
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug true -e class 'com.<package_name>.ExampleInstrumentedTest' com.<package_name>.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Waiting for application to come online: com.<package_name>.debug.test | com.<package_name>.debug
Connecting to com.<package_name>.debug
```

maybe better use a [TestRule](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-rules) to mock parameter input.

one can also pass `android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class` alike:

```
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -P android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.<package_name>.ExampleInstrumentedTest#someMethodToTest
```

or pass further arguments alike

```
-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.argument1=make_test_fail
```

while one can run whole groups of tests (eg. `EspressoTest`) alike:

```
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.android.testing.blueprint.ui.espresso.EspressoTest
```

see the [Android Testing Blueprint](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint).