# Testing custom Views with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm trying to run unit tests with Robolectric 2.1.1 and I cannot get it to inflate custom layouts (e.g. ViewPagerIndicator classes). 
Suppose this is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:id="@+id/test_test"/>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Consider this my test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TestRoboActivityTest {
    private TestRoboActivity mActivity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(TestRoboActivity.class).create().get();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mActivity = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSanity() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(mActivity);
    }
}
```

Executing 'mvn clean test' results in

```
Tests in error:
testSanity(TestRoboActivityTest): XML file .\res\layout\test.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
```

Cool, so it seems like custom views aren't supported yet. Checking the sample Robolectric project on their [website](https://github.com/robolectric/RobolectricSample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/pivotallabs/views/LoadingTextViewTest.java), 
one solution could be to inflate the layout from LayoutInflater:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TestRoboActivityTest {
    private View mTestRoboActivityView;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mTestRoboActivityView = LayoutInflater.from(new Activity()).inflate(R.layout.test, null);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mTestRoboActivityView = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSanity() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(mTestRoboActivityView);
    }
}
```

which results in:

```
Tests in error: 
testSanity(TestRoboActivityTest): XML file .\res\layout\test.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
```

My last resort was trying to use shadow classes:

```
@Implements(CirclePageIndicator.class)
public class CirclePageIndicatorShadow implements PageIndicator {

    @Override
    @Implementation
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager view) {
        // Stub
    }

    // etc.
}
```

and using `@Config(shadows = {CirclePageIndicatorShadow.class})`. This again resulted in

```
Tests in error: 
testSanity(TestRoboActivityTest): XML file .\res\layout\test.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
```

---

**Edit (December 2014)**

Please note that the following stracktrace was added later by David Rabinowitz. While related, it is not the issue I was facing at the time.

---

Here is the stack trace:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file .\res\layout\activity_home.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class com.test.custom.RobotoTextView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:82)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:273)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at com.example.testrobocustomfont.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    at com.example.testrobocustomfont.MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:241)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:82)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:273)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$ShadowMethodPlan.run(ShadowWrangler.java:455)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at com.example.testrobocustomfont.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    at com.example.testrobocustomfont.MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error converting RobotoMedium.ttf using EnumConverter
    at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter.convertAndFill(Converter.java:150)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter.convertAndFill(Converter.java:50)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.createTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:228)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:203)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.access$000(ShadowResources.java:51)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:460)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java)
    at android.widget.TextView.__constructor__(TextView.java:561)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:447)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:442)
    at com.test.custom.RobotoTextView.<init>(RobotoTextView.java:16)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:82)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:273)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at com.example.testrobocustomfont.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    at com.example.testrobocustomfont.MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:28)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: no value found for RobotoMedium.ttf
    at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter$EnumOrFlagConverter.findValueFor(Converter.java:375)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter$EnumConverter.fillTypedValue(Converter.java:343)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter$EnumConverter.fillTypedValue(Converter.java:336)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter.convertAndFill(Converter.java:148)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter.convertAndFill(Converter.java:50)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.createTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:228)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:203)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.access$000(ShadowResources.java:51)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:460)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$ShadowMethodPlan.run(ShadowWrangler.java:455)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java)
    at android.widget.TextView.$$robo$$TextView_347d___constructor__(TextView.java:561)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:447)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:442)
    at com.test.custom.RobotoTextView.<init>(RobotoTextView.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:82)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:273)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$ShadowMethodPlan.run(ShadowWrangler.java:455)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at com.example.testrobocustomfont.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    at com.example.testrobocustomfont.MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    ... 22 more
```

Could you guys please point me in the right direction? I'm out of ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: Are you using a custom font, or a custom view that uses a custom font? I think @joecks is on the right track with their answer. Android can't render custom fonts in a preview (ie, when you're looking at the xml in Eclipse), and the same problem may be occurring here. If you control the text view, try wrapping the code that retrieves the style with `if (!isInEditMode())`

Comment: Are you able to see the custom view in the layout xml graphical preview?

Comment: Similar: [Testing ViewPager (and CursorLoader) with Robolectric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346484/testing-viewpager-and-cursorloader-with-robolectric)

Comment: I can test custom views. Maybe something is wrong with your custom view. Try making a temporary and very simple custom view (basically just extend button or textview). Plug in this simple custom view where your current view is. See if it still complains about that.

Comment: Could the OP post his/her stack trace in order that we might help? Having someone else's stack trace is not very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ? I am facing the same kind of issue.

Comment: Refer to [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4913875/8583692).

Answer (score 5):

I test views in the same test class with the Activity that uses them. In this case I tell Robolectric to give an instance of that Activity and from that I get an instance of the inflated view:

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create().get();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.myView, null);
}
@Test
 public void allElementsInViewProduct(){
     assertNotNull(view.findViewById(R.id.view1));
     assertNotNull(view.findViewById(R.id.view2));
     assertNotNull(view.findViewById(R.id.view3));
 }
```

LE: I use Robolectric 3.0 so I am not sure if this applies to you.

Answer (score 4):

### Problem:

This issue happens, because gradle merges project dependencies (ex: `compile project(':lib-custom')`) and external dependencies (ex: `compile 'lib.package:name:1.1.0'`) in different way. After dependencies were merged app has `R.java` file with all resources fields (colors, ids, drawables, ...). But generated `R.java` file looks different after merging submodules and external dependencies.

**This problem exists only with projects, which have custom views in submodules**. In case of external dependencies there is another issues, which can be easily fixed. Read about dependencies types [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html).

For project dependencies result `R.java` file contains all resource identifiers, but identifiers from submodule doesn't equals to their original integer identifiers:

```
com.lib.custom.R.color.primary != com.main.project.R.color.primary
```

For external dependencies merged `R.java` file just a merge result of R.java files from all external dependencies

```
com.lib.custom.R.color.primary == com.main.project.R.color.primary
```

### Solution:

I've found two possible solutions:

1. Convert your dependencies from submodule to external where possible. For example for viepager indicator has an item in maven.org repository - fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library.
   But this is still not enough - you need to add related item to project.properties file to your main sourceSet. More info [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1334)

Example:

```
// add this dependency to your gradle file instead of project dependency
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

// add library dependencies for robolectric (now robolectric knows 
// about additional libraries to load resources)
android.library.reference.1=../../../app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator/library/2.4.1
```

You can check diff for this solution [here](https://github.com/AlexanderTolstykh/RobolectricCustomViews/commit/a01ff4cd724bb3b78ec32ddafc3bd52888fdf040)

2. Move all your custom views under your main app. It is not good approach to move Custom views to app only because of unit testing, but this will also fix issue with `Error inflating class`.

I prefer first solution but it is not possible sometimes change project dependency to external.

I am also going to report about this issue to Robolectric team.

P.S. I have [project on github](https://github.com/AlexanderTolstykh/RobolectricCustomViews) related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`mTestRoboActivityView = LayoutInflater.from(new Activity()).inflate(R.layout.test, null);`

In this line of code you used 'new Activity()' means instance of new Activity, that not for your current Activity.
You can resolve this issue by passing instance on current Activity.
Use like this-

```
public class TestRoboActivityTest {
private View mTestRoboActivityView;
private Context mContext;

public TestRoboActivityTest(Context mContext){
    this.mContext=mContext;
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mTestRoboActivityView = (LayoutInflater.from(mContext)).inflate(R.layout.test, null);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mTestRoboActivityView = null;
}

@Test
public void testSanity() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertNotNull(mTestRoboActivityView);
}}
```

I am not sure that above code working fine but use for reference, instance of current Activity.
Refer it may be help you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inflate views in Roboelectric since it does not use the complete android framework but instead mocks out all the Android API's.

You should not use roboelectric to test actual view display behavior.
It is to be used for unit tests and just to test your business logic and not view drawing/display etc. To achieve that You can programmatically create view objects and mock out certain parts which need the android system (Use something like **Mockito or Powermock**).
eg of simple view testing in roboelectic:

```
MyCustomView view = new MyCustomView();
assertNotNull(view.setSomeNo(2);
assertTrue(2, view.getSomeNo());
```

Also if you want to test rendering of how your view looks or renders etc, you should use functional testing frameworks such as **Espresso** or **Robotium** which run on an actual device.