# How to take screenshot at the point where test fail in Espresso?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am looking for a way to take a screenshot of device after test failed and before get closed.

Comment: You can use Spoon (http://square.github.io/spoon/) library for this purpose.

Comment: Refer to [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4913875/8583692).

Answer (score 20):

Easiest way that I found:

```
@Rule
public TestRule watcher = new TestWatcher() {
  @Override
  protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
    // Save to external storage (usually /sdcard/screenshots)
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        + "/screenshots/" + getTargetContext().getPackageName());
    if (!path.exists()) {
      path.mkdirs();
    }

    // Take advantage of UiAutomator screenshot method
    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    String filename = description.getClassName() + "-" + description.getMethodName() + ".png";
    device.takeScreenshot(new File(path, filename));
  }
};
```

Comment: I end up with this error: failed to save screen shot to file
                                                                       java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/screenshots/com.myappname/asdffdsa.png (No such file or directory)

Comment: Fixed the above by granting write external storage permissions. Now my issue is that the above code doesn't get called when a test fails. I tried the code in a manual call and it worked, but I can't get it to work upon failure automatically.

Comment: @ZeekAran instead of using a `TestWatcher` try registering espresso failure handler as described here https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/recipes#using-custom-failure-handler

Comment: I ended up doing it this way:
@After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {<code>}
        AfterTestCleanup.tearDown();
    }

Answer (score 17):

Another improvement to previous answers. I'm using the experimental [Screenshot API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/screenshot/Screenshot.html)

```
public class ScreenshotTestRule extends TestWatcher {

  @Override
  protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
    super.failed(e, description);

    takeScreenshot(description);
  }

  private void takeScreenshot(Description description) {
    String filename = description.getTestClass().getSimpleName() + "-" + description.getMethodName();

    ScreenCapture capture = Screenshot.capture();
    capture.setName(filename);
    capture.setFormat(CompressFormat.PNG);

    HashSet<ScreenCaptureProcessor> processors = new HashSet<>();
    processors.add(new CustomScreenCaptureProcessor());

    try {
      capture.process(processors);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I've created *CustomScreenCaptureProcessor* because [BasicScreenCaptureProcessor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/screenshot/BasicScreenCaptureProcessor.html) uses */sdcard/Pictures/* folder and I encountered IOExceptions on some devices when creating the folder/image. Please note that you need to place your processor in the same package

```
package android.support.test.runner.screenshot;

public class CustomScreenCaptureProcessor extends BasicScreenCaptureProcessor {    
  public CustomScreenCaptureProcessor() {
    super(
        new File(
            InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "espresso_screenshots"
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Then, in your base Espresso test class just add

```
@Rule
public ScreenshotTestRule screenshotTestRule = new ScreenshotTestRule();
```

If you wish to use some protected folder, this did the trick on an emulator, tho it didn't work on a physical device

```
@Rule
public RuleChain screenshotRule = RuleChain
      .outerRule(GrantPermissionRule.grant(permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
      .around(new ScreenshotTestRule());
```

Comment: This did work, but I have to use the `CustomScreenCaptureProcessor`. Otherwise I get this: `java.io.IOException: The directory /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/screenshots does not exist and could not be created or is not writable.`.

Comment: Could you update my answer with the details? I'm also experiencing that every now and then, but I haven't had the time to look into it.

Comment: Hi @Maragues not sure if I understand what you want. I just used the `CustomScreenCaptureProcessor` you provided. There's nothing I did that it's not on your answer.

Comment: Hint: screenshots are saved in _storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{package}/files/Pictures/espresso_screenshots_. It took me a while find them! You can grab them all at once with the Android Studio Device File Explorer (right click on the folder -> Save As...).

Comment: More details at https://medium.com/stepstone-tech/how-to-capture-screenshots-for-failed-ui-tests-9927eea6e1e4

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo if you use a Google System image on the emulator the _storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{package}/files/Pictures/espresso_screenshots_ can be found in _/sdcard/Android/data/{package}/files/Pictures/espresso_screenshots_ since it's a symlink.

Answer (score 7):

[@Maragues](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218473/maragues) answer ported to Kotlin:

Helper classes:

```
package utils

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation
import androidx.test.runner.screenshot.BasicScreenCaptureProcessor
import androidx.test.runner.screenshot.ScreenCaptureProcessor
import androidx.test.runner.screenshot.Screenshot
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher
import org.junit.runner.Description
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException

class IDTScreenCaptureProcessor : BasicScreenCaptureProcessor() {
    init {
        mTag = "IDTScreenCaptureProcessor"
        mFileNameDelimiter = "-"
        mDefaultFilenamePrefix = "Giorgos"
        mDefaultScreenshotPath = getNewFilename()
    }

    private fun getNewFilename(): File? {
        val context = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext()
        return context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    }
}

class ScreenshotTestRule : TestWatcher() {
    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)

        val className = description?.testClass?.simpleName ?: "NullClassname"
        val methodName = description?.methodName ?: "NullMethodName"
        val filename = "$className - $methodName"

        val capture = Screenshot.capture()
        capture.name = filename
        capture.format = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG

        val processors = HashSet<ScreenCaptureProcessor>()
        processors.add(IDTScreenCaptureProcessor())

        try {
            capture.process(processors)
        } catch (ioException: IOException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isCompletelyDisplayed
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import utils.ScreenshotTestRule

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class DialogActivityTest {

    @get:Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(DialogActivity::class.java)

    @get:Rule
    val screenshotTestRule = ScreenshotTestRule()

    @Test
    fun dialogLaunch_withTitleAndBody_displaysDialog() {
        // setup
        val title = "title"
        val body = "body"

        // assert
        onView(withText(title)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()))
        onView(withText(body)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()))
    }


}
```

Libraries declared in app's `build.gradle`:

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.1.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.1.1"
```

This setup saves a screenshot **every time** a test finished in the folder: `/sdcard/Android/data/your.package.name/files/Pictures`
Navigate there via Android Studio's Device File Explorer (on the right sidebar)

If you like to save screenshots only for failed tests, override the `failed` method of `TestWatcher` instead of the `finished`

Answer (score 4):

Writing a custom TestWatcher like the other answers explained is the way to go.

**BUT** (and it took us a long time to notice it) there is a caveat: The rule *might* fire too late, i.e. after your activity was already destroyed. This leaves you with a screenshot of the device's home screen and not from the failing activity.

You can solve this using [RuleChain](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html): Instead of writing

```
@Rule
public final ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> _activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Rule
public ScreenshotTestWatcher _screenshotWatcher = new ScreenshotTestWatcher();
```

You have to write:

```
private final ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> _activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Rule
public final TestRule activityAndScreenshotRule = RuleChain
        .outerRule(_activityRule)
        .around(new ScreenshotTestWatcher());
```

This makes sure that the screenshot is taken first and then the activity is destroyed

Comment: Sadly I still only get pictures of the home screen.

Comment: Well, I got it to work. I overlooked that you need to remove the `@Rule` for the activity. I also noted that there is also a new `@get:org.junit.Rule(order = 2)` feature which works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I made some improvements on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42167655/2212770) answer. No need to add an extra dependency for UiAutomator and it also works below api level 18.

```
public class ScreenshotTestWatcher extends TestWatcher
{
   private static Activity currentActivity;

   @Override
   protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description)
   {
      Bitmap bitmap;

      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
      {
         bitmap = getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().takeScreenshot();
      }
      else
      {
         // only in-app view-elements are visible.
         bitmap = Screenshot.capture(getCurrentActivity()).getBitmap();
      }

      // Save to external storage '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[package name app]/cache/screenshots/'.
      File folder = new File(getTargetContext().getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/screenshots/");
      if (!folder.exists())
      {
         folder.mkdirs();
      }

      storeBitmap(bitmap, folder.getPath() + "/" + getFileName(description));
   }

   private String getFileName(Description description)
   {
      String className = description.getClassName();
      String methodName = description.getMethodName();
      String dateTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString();

      return className + "-" + methodName + "-" + dateTime + ".png";
   }

   private void storeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String path)
   {
      BufferedOutputStream out = null;
      try
      {
         out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
         if (out != null)
         {
            try
            {
               out.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private static Activity getCurrentActivity()
   {
      getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable()
         {
            public void run()
            {
               Collection resumedActivities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(
                     RESUMED);
               if (resumedActivities.iterator().hasNext())
               {
                  currentActivity = (Activity) resumedActivities.iterator().next();
               }
            }
         });

      return currentActivity;
   }
}
```

Then include the following line in your test class:

```
@Rule
public TestRule watcher = new ScreenshotTestWatcher();
```

Answer (score 0):

A compilation of the other suggestions, comments and some of my own. I was having issues with the screenshot not being taken within the TestWatcher failed function. Instead using a custom FailureHandler, since it was only mentioned and no example provided, here goes...

```
class ScreenshotRule : TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        super.starting(description)
        setFailureHandler(
            CustomFailureHandler(getInstrumentation().targetContext, description)
        )
    }
}

class CustomFailureHandler(targetContext: Context, description: Description) : FailureHandler {

    private val delegate: FailureHandler
    private val device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
    private val directory = "/sdcard/Pictures/screenshots/failures"
    private val testClassName = description.className
    private val testMethodName = description.methodName

    init {
        delegate = DefaultFailureHandler(targetContext)
    }

    override fun handle(error: Throwable, viewMatcher: Matcher<View>) {
        val snapshot = File("$directory/$testClassName", "$testMethodName.png")
        snapshot.parentFile!!.mkdirs()
        device.takeScreenshot(snapshot)

        delegate.handle(error, viewMatcher)
    }
}
```

I have this Rule ordered after my 'GrantPermissionRule' and 'activityScenarioRule'

Also couldn't trust the Environment dirs `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `targetContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_SCREENSHOTS)` so just providing my own to the `sdcard/Pictures/screenshots`.
Maybe someone can help improve the use of MediaStore...

Comment: How do you grab it from a managed device in gradle?  my CI runs the managed device and we do the UI tests on it.  Unclear how to grab this