# Unable to store Espresso Failure Screenshots on android 10 devices

Tags: kotlin, automation, screenshot, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

Since the improved privacy changes on Android 10 [Android 10 Privacy changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes), I've noticed that my screenshot failure test watcher rule in Kotlin, that extends the Espresso BasicScreenCaptureProcessor no longer saves failure screenshots because I am using the deprecated `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` on Android 10.

The concept currently implement is very similar to [How to take screenshot at the point where test fail in Espresso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519568/how-to-take-screenshot-at-the-point-where-test-fail-in-espresso/54479660#54479660)

```
class TestScreenCaptureProcessor : BasicScreenCaptureProcessor() {
    init {
        this.mDefaultScreenshotPath = File(
            File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "Failure_Screenshots"
            ).absolutePath
        )
    }
```

As seen in other posts, I could use the `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

that would store the file in - `/sdcard/Android/data/your.package.name/files/Pictures` directory, but the `connectedAndroidTest` gradle task deletes the app at the end along with it the folders listed above.

I wondered if anyone else had come across something similar and has considered a way of storing failure screenshots on Android 10, in a location that will not be deleted when the tests have finished running & somewhere that Espresso Instrumentation tests can access.

My UI tests are run on a variety of devices, so need a generic way of storing the files is required to suite all models.

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of research I found a way to save screenshots in kotlin based on the SDK version using MediaStore.

```
/**
 * storeFailureScreenshot will store the bitmap based on the SDK level of the 
 * device. Due to security improvements and changes to how data can be accessed in 
 * SDK levels >=29 Failure screenshots will be stored in 
 * sdcard/DIRECTORY_PICTURES/Failure_Screenshots.
 */
fun storeFailureScreenshot(bitmap: Bitmap, screenshotName: String) {
    val contentResolver = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.applicationContext.contentResolver

    // Check SDK version of device to determine how to save the screenshot.
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        useMediaStoreScreenshotStorage(
            contentValues,
            contentResolver,
            screenshotName,
            SCREENSHOT_FOLDER_LOCATION,
            bitmap
        )
    } else {
        usePublicExternalScreenshotStorage(
            contentValues,
            contentResolver,
            screenshotName,
            SCREENSHOT_FOLDER_LOCATION,
            bitmap
        )
    }
}

/**
 * This will be used by devices with SDK versions >=29. This is to overcome scoped 
 * storage considerations now in the SDK version listed to help limit file 
 * clutter. A Uniform resource identifier (Uri) is used to insert bitmap into
 * the gallery using the contentValues previously specified. The contentResolver 
 * provides application access to content model to access and publish data in a 
 * secure manner, using MediaStore collections to do so. Files will
 * be stored in sdcard/Pictures
 */
private fun useMediaStoreScreenshotStorage(
    contentValues: ContentValues,
    contentResolver: ContentResolver,
    screenshotName: String,
    screenshotLocation: String,
    bitmap: Bitmap
) {
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "$screenshotName.jpeg")
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + screenshotLocation)

    val uri: Uri? = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
    if (uri != null) {
        contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.let { saveScreenshotToStream(bitmap, it) }
        contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)
    }
}

/**
 * Method to access internal storage on a handset with SDK version below 29. 
 * Directory will be in sdcard/Pictures. Relevant sub directories will be created 
 * & screenshot will be stored as a .jpeg file.
 */
private fun usePublicExternalScreenshotStorage(
    contentValues: ContentValues,
    contentResolver: ContentResolver,
    screenshotName: String,
    screenshotLocation: String,
    bitmap: Bitmap
) {
    val directory = File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + screenshotLocation).toString())

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs()
    }

    val file = File(directory, "$screenshotName.jpeg")
    saveScreenshotToStream(bitmap, FileOutputStream(file))

    val values = contentValues
    contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
}

/**
 * Assigns the assignments about the Image media including, image type & date 
 * taken. Content values are used so the contentResolver can interpret them. These 
 * are applied to the contentValues object.
 */
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
}

/**
 * Compresses the bitmap object to a .jpeg image format using the specified
 * OutputStream of bytes.
 */
private fun saveScreenshotToStream(bitmap: Bitmap, outputStream: OutputStream) {
    outputStream.use {
        try {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, it)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Timber.e("Screenshot was not stored at this time")
        }
    }
}
```

Used in conjunction with a TestWatcher that takes a screenshot on a UI test failure. This is then added to the test class as a rule.

```
private val deviceLanguage = Locale.getDefault().language

/**
 * Finds current date and time & is put into format of Wed-Mar-06-15:52:17.
 */
fun getDate(): String = SimpleDateFormat("EEE-MMMM-dd-HH:mm:ss").format(Date())

/**
 * ScreenshotFailureRule overrides TestWatcher failed rule and instead takes a 
 * screenshot using the UI Automation takeScreenshot method and the 
 * storeFailureScreenshot to decide where to store the bitmap when a failure 
 * occurs.
 */
class ScreenshotFailureRule : TestWatcher() {
    override fun failed(e: Throwable?, description: Description) {
        val screenShotName = "$deviceLanguage-${description.methodName}-${getDate()}"
        val bitmap = getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.takeScreenshot()
        storeFailureScreenshot(bitmap, screenShotName)
    }
}
```

file is stored in `sdcard/Pictures/Failure_Screenshots` with a name of
`en-testMethodName-Day-Month-Date-HH_MM_SS`

Rule called using:

```
val screenshotFailureRule = ScreenshotFailureRule()
```

Comment: This is awesome and thanks for sharing it. This probably works fantastic on a CI but on my local, any images created during run #1 cannot be overwritten on run #2 because the app no longer owns those files.

Comment: So how do I grab these from a gradle managed device