# Gradle: adding assets folder dynamically

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a project with many flavors, for each flavor I have a configuration file which specifies which assets to include.

here is what I have so far:

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def config = getFlavourConfig(variant.getFlavorName());
        if(config!=null) {
            if(config.get("font-assets") != null ) {
                config.get("font-assets").each {
                    println it
/*this is not working ->*/ variant.assets.srcDirs += ['src/extensions/assets/'+it]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

getFlavourConfig parses a gson configuration file. The json has ["font-assets":["fontfolder1","fontfolder2"]

In this line

```
variant.assets.srcDirs += ['src/extensions/assets/'+it]
```

I want to add the assets dir to the flavor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using one flavour at a build time and used the following line:

```
android.sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs += ['src/extensions/assets/'+it]
```

Answer (score 4):

You might be overthinking the work required.  Just create the `productFlavor` then define the flavor's `assets.srcDirs`.  Now we can sit back and let Android's gradle plugin do all the work.

```
android {
    //...
    productFlavors {
        blah {}
        more {}
    }
    sourceSets {
        blah {
            assets.srcDirs = files(getFlavorConfig(it.name))
        }
        more {
            assets.srcDirs = files(getFlavorConfig(it.name))
        }
    }
}

// simplified method for example
def getFlavorConfig(String str) {
    return ["$projectDir.absolutePath/src/extensions/assets/first", "$projectDir.absolutePath/src/extensions/assets/second"];
}
```

After the build our files will be where we expect:

```
$ ls app/build/intermediates/assets/blah/debug/
hello.txt world.txt

$ ls app/build/intermediates/assets/more/debug/
hello.txt world.txt

$ ls app/build/intermediates/assets/blah/release/
hello.txt world.txt

$ ls app/build/intermediates/assets/more/release/
hello.txt world.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is that the flavor is generated by a server side script (by modifying the build.gradle file). In order to do as you suggested I would need to edit the script, which I don't want to do.