# How to normally record and verify screenshot tests in android

Tags: android

I tried putting in the android [screenshot testing library](https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android) written by facebook.

I set up everything as described in the wiki, and then wrote my test, which displayed on the simulator well when i ran it manually. But I want to run it from the command line

So i wrote this line in the command line

```
 ./gradlew :instrumentationtestmodule:recordDevDebugAndroidTestScreenshotTest --tests=com.path.to.test.explicit.TestClass --stacktrace
```

And it started running

1. connectedAndroidTest
2. All the possible tests in the other classes
3. Did not run the record screenshot test.

None of the above is what I wanted to achieve.
How do I record 1 specific test with the android screenshot test?

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69259011/8583692) helps you.